# Elixir Sleep / Wait for 1 Second

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

How to sleep / wait for one second?

Best I could find was something like this (in iex):

```
IO.puts "foo" ; :timer.sleep(1); IO.puts "bar"
```

But both of my puts happen with no delay.

Comment: Also in Elixir 1.3 you can use `Process.sleep` instead of calling erlang.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Timer uses milliseconds not seconds, update to:

```
IO.puts "foo" ; :timer.sleep(1000); IO.puts "bar"
```

Documentation of :timer in Erlang's doc:

> Suspends the process calling this function for Time amount of
>   milliseconds and then returns ok, or suspend the process forever if
>   Time is the atom infinity. Naturally, this function does not return
>   immediately.

http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#sleep-1

Comment: There are useful helpers in the timer module to specify time intervals. For example: `:timer.sleep(:timer.seconds(1))`

Answer (score 89):

Since Elixir 1.3 you can use **[`Process.sleep/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#sleep/1)**:

```
Process.sleep(1000)
```

The argument is in milliseconds.